# How can I contribute and add a new feature in Magento 2 via github?

Tags: magento2, github

I want the Magento 2 `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl` class to handle all http methods.

I have added as a feature request in `magento/community-feature` repo on github. How can I add the feature myself ?

https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/101